# Why these 2 columns won't align?

Tags: html, css

HTML :

```
    <div id="main">
        <br class="clearfloat" />
        <div id="#left">
        </div>
        <div id="#right">
        </div>
        <br class="clearfloat" />
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
#main  {
    clear: both;
    width: 1110px;

}
#left {
    width: 801px;
    float: right;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 280px;
}
```

I can't for the life of me understand why the #left and #right columns won't be side by side... #right is showing under #left, even if they are properly floated and have the right dimension in pixels to fit side by side.

Comment: Possible, id="left" instead of id="#left"? And many other selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, `id` should not contain `#`

The corrected code is :

```
<div id="main">

    <br class="clearfloat" />

    <div id="left">
    </div>

    <div id="right">
    </div>

    <br class="clearfloat" />

</div>
```

The `#` is purely used by CSS to reference IDs

Comment: I just realized the same thing after taking a break and coming back to look at my code. *facepalm* 

Thanks Addikted!